# Play framework 2.2.1 - alternative cache?

Tags: java, caching, memcached, ehcache, playframework-2.2

I'm developing an app that saves generated random tokens for users after they authenticate. 
I save those tokens in the cache using play's default cache product .
Every token i save to my cache is an instance of class with 5 String properties.

I have 2 questions :
1. Is there a better cache product (for java) that i should use to manage my cache?

2. It seems to be that the expiriation is not working. Is t a known bug?
3. There is a way to clean all the cache? I cant fina any.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Can you please add some code snippets? Actually you are asking for three different things.

Comment: Amm im actually dont intersted in code issues.. I realy need help in choosing the optimal cache product for my web application ( ehcache, redis or memcache are the options i think) . Also it would be great if you can show some implementations of those products in a play java application. Thank!